# Admob Test Ads In The Emulator

Tags: admob, vb4android

I followed the tutorial and put the admob code into a test app and everything seemed to work and I saw the test ads displayed on the screen. I'm not sure why test ads instead of real appeared on the screen, but the code seemed to be working. When I put the admob code into the real app, I no longer see the test ads. Logcat shows "failed: Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory", so I'm not getting any ads on the screen. I'm not sure what I did to disable the test ads, and I'm not sure how to bring them back. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"Lack of inventory" means that there are no ads to show.... try later.

Also, have you tried to add Google AdSense adds in your admob control panel ? It can help a **little**!